# Font-awesome for after?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

When I use

```
<i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>
```

It will show an angle  down, but when I add this to css it will show a square that means error, but there's nothing in console log.

```
.dropbtn:after {
    font-family: "Font Awesome\ 5 Free";
    content: "\f107";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 4px;
    line-height: 1;
}
```

How can I solve this? Thank you.

Comment: I'd say either the `font-family` is wrong or the `content` is wrong.

Comment: The font family is font-family: 'FontAwesome'

Comment: I tried `font-family: 'FontAwesome'`  but it didn't work, that `.fa-angle-down:before {
    content: "\f107";
}`
and 
`.fa, .far, .fas {
    font-family: Font Awesome\ 5 Free;
}`
is originated form font awesome, I just copied.